# Does a Revit command have to be passed as a relay command using WPF and MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, revit-api

I have a few external commands that work perfectly when called by a pulldown button in Revit. I was attempting to upgrade the code by creating a list of commands in a WPF window using the MVVM pattern - mostly. There are no models in these cases instead a service that speaks to the Revit file. Below is an example of a service executes a call to remove materials:

```
using Autodesk.Revit.Attributes;
using Autodesk.Revit.DB;
using Autodesk.Revit.UI;

namespace DevTools.Services.Cleaner
{
    [Transaction(TransactionMode.Manual)]
    [Regeneration(RegenerationOption.Manual)]
    [Journaling(JournalingMode.NoCommandData)]
    public class PurgeAllMaterialsService : IExternalCommand
    {
        public Result Execute(ExternalCommandData commandData, ref string message, ElementSet elements)
        {
            var uiDoc = commandData.Application.ActiveUIDocument;
            var doc = uiDoc.Document;
        try
        {
            using Transaction trans = new(doc, "Delete all materials");

            var allMaterials = new FilteredElementCollector(doc)
                .OfClass(typeof(Material))
                .ToElementIds();

            var count = 0;

            trans.Start();
            foreach (var id in allMaterials)
            {
                try
                {
                    var m = doc.GetElement(id) as Material;
                    {
                        uiDoc.Document.Delete(id);
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    message = ex.Message;
                    return Result.Failed;
                }
            }
            trans.Commit();
            TaskDialog.Show("Delete All Materials", count + " materials have been deleted");
            return Result.Succeeded;
        }
        catch (Autodesk.Revit.Exceptions.OperationCanceledException)
        {
            return Result.Cancelled;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            message = ex.Message;
            return Result.Failed;
        }
    }
}
}
```

The view-model calls the service in a relay command

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using DevTools.Services.Cleaner;

namespace DevTools.ViewModels
{
    public partial class CleanerViewModel
    {
        private PurgeAllMaterialsService _purgeAllMaterialsService;

        [RelayCommand]
        private void PurgeAllMaterials()
        {
            _purgeAllMaterialsService = new PurgeAllMaterialsService();
            
        }
    }
}
```

and the command passes the service to the view.

```
using Autodesk.Revit.Attributes;
using DevTools.Services.Cleaner;
using DevTools.ViewModels;
using DevTools.Views;
using Nice3point.Revit.Toolkit.External;

namespace DevTools.Commands
{
    [UsedImplicitly]
    [Transaction(TransactionMode.Manual)]
    public class CleanWindowCommand : ExternalCommand
    {
        public override void Execute()
        {
            var viewModel = new CleanerViewModel();
            var view = new CleanerPage(viewModel);
            view.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

in the view the command is called by a button like so.

```xml
<Button Content="Purge Materials"
        Command="{Binding PurgeAllMaterialsCommand, Mode=OneWay}"
        Width="200"
        Height="28"
        Margin="0,10,0,0"
        BorderBrush="Transparent"
        Background="{StaticResource HeaderBackgroundBrush}"
        Foreground="{StaticResource LightBrush}" />
```

The problem is the button does not execute the command. What is missing? Is the WPF window blocking the command bein sent?

Comment: There are several glitches in your code, but the main point is, that the Command you bound to the Command property has to implement the `ICommand` interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Command` property of the `Button` must be set or bound to an object that implements the `System.Windows.Input.ICommand` interface.

So the `PurgeMaterialCommand` property of your view model should return an `ICommand` implementation. The `Execute(object parameter)` method will then be called when you invoke the command by clicking on the button.

Comment: Could you elaborate more with a code sample ?

Comment: @MostafaTarekYassien I edited the code above to use MS Community Toolkit relay command in the view model still cannot get the button to perform  the command. I tested the relay command with a messagebox.show and the button opens the message box.